# NodeJS crypto.createHmac doesn't have the same result as PHP's hash_hmac

Tags: php, node.js, cryptography, jwt, hmac

I'm trying to verify a JWT token from PHP to Node but failed when getting the token's signature value in Node's `crypto.createHmac`. Both use the same secret key

JWT token to validate:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6MTg3fQ.HWVnV0i9dtHdS4snqCSDkgLjCdvnTYQ2d3t7I834C9s
```

PHP:

```
base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", "$headb64.$bodyb64", $someSecretKey, true))
```

results to

```
HWVnV0i9dtHdS4snqCSDkgLjCdvnTYQ2d3t7I834C9s=
```

but in Node

```
crypto.createHmac("sha256", Buffer.from(process.env.SOME_SECRET_KEY))
        .update(`${header}.${payload}`)
        .digest('base64')
```

I got

```
ryvyuqcW_GbVhPNBAyW8fGR1i911Jh_FFsNIPf1DJOc=
```

I know there are so many questions the same as this but their solutions were not working on mine. I googled this problem many times but failed, creating a question is my last resort. I'm using PHP 5.6 and Node v12.13.1.

Any solution for this? thank you.

Comment: I _cannot_ reproduce the problem with my own data (key and JWT), i.e. I get the _same_ hash (which equals the JWT hash) with both the PHP code (5.6.40) and the NodeJS code (10.16.0 and 12.11.1). If your key is a _test_ key it should be posted so that the original data can also be checked. You should re-check the data (headerB64.payloadB64) and the key of the NodeJS code. Maybe there is a difference here after all. E.g. are `${header}.${payload}` also the _Base64 encoded_ data?

Comment: Thank you! the problem was the key, so stupid of me, I thought the API uses the key in the environment variable but when I checked it didn't, it was hardcoded :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Topaco mentions in a comment:

> I *cannot* reproduce the problem with my own data (key and JWT), i.e. I get the *same* hash (which equals the JWT hash) with both the PHP code (5.6.40) and the NodeJS code (10.16.0 and 12.11.1). If your key is a *test* key it should be posted so that the original data can also be checked. You should re-check the data (headerB64.payloadB64) and the key of the NodeJS code. Maybe there is a difference here after all. E.g. are `${header}.${payload}` also the *Base64 encoded* data?

The problem was the secret key. I was so confident that PHP uses the key in the environment variable but when I checked it wasn't, the key was hardcoded in the config file.